# Where can I see print output in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using Android Studio to develop an app with flutter and i need to print things to the console for debugging but i have no idea where to view the output as it doesn't show up in the console. I apologize if this is a stupid question but i am very new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Where

When you run Flutter program, your ouput (e.g. from `print(...)`) will be in `Run` tab in:

[image]

## How to show this

It should enable with ever app install.
But if not, you van show this tab manually from:

```
View -> Toogle Windows -> Run
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can use log like this (Run Tab):

```
log('data: $data');
```

Or DebugPrint like this (Run Tab):

```
debugPrint('yourMessage');
```

Or print like this (Run Tab):

```
print("Data");
```